# SQL Server 2019 install - Python and R failing

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2019

I'm installing SQL 2019 Enterprise on the first node of a failover cluster.  Everything successfully installs except Python and R.  Error messages are as follows:

```
  Feature:                       Python
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                Machine Learning Services and Language Extensions
  Component error code:          -2147467261
  Error description:             Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: accountName
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.4013.40&EvtType=0xB05283BE%400x11428655&EvtType=0xB05283BE%400x11428655

  Feature:                       R
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                Machine Learning Services and Language Extensions
  Component error code:          -2147467261
  Error description:             Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: accountName
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.4013.40&EvtType=0xB05283BE%400x11428655&EvtType=0xB05283BE%400x11428655
```

Haven't found anything online about that error message with accountName specifically.  Of course the link provided in the error message redirects to generic Microsoft page.

I believe Python and R are the features that download the extra cab files during setup, and I usually see a "downloading file xxxxx.cab (8XX MB)" during installation for a while, but I'm not seeing it this time.  Not sure if that's related.

Windows firewall is turned off, and Anti-Virus is disabled (I think, may need to look more into this, but nothing in the AV logs about something getting blocked).

EDIT: The server does have internet access.

EDIT2: According to [THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/install/sql-machine-learning-services-windows-install?view=sql-server-ver15) link, machine learning services were not supported on 2017 failover clusters, but they are supported on 2019+ failover clusters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.  Apparently the null accountName in the error message was the account name for SQL Launchpad, which was blank during the install for some reason.  I repeated the install and gave SQL Launchpad an account name of NT Service\MSSQLLaunchpad, and everything installed correctly.